# Using Jquery with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am developing a program to negotiate with the user. I want the user to quote the price, that price must be stored in a javascript variable and then based on some conditions, the program will decide wether to accept the price or not.

I have completed the program in PHP, but I am unable to write this in javascript (I don't want the page to be refreshed every time the user quotes a price, so I have to write this in javascript )  as I am new to it.

As soon as the user presses the accept price button I want the final price to be passed to  PHP .

Here is my PHP code for it :

```
<?php



if (isset($_POST['accept'])) {

    echo 'Price Accepted';



if (isset($_SESSION['my_quote'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart_total']=$_SESSION['my_quote'];
        }

unset($_SESSION['my_quote']);
    //NOW PLACING THE ORDER

    header("Location:checkout.php");

} else {

    if (isset($_POST['user_quote']) && !empty($_POST['user_quote'])) {

        $user_quote = sanitize($_POST['user_quote']);


        if (!isset($_SESSION['my_quote'])) {
            $_SESSION['my_quote']=$_SESSION['cart_total'];
        }


        if ($user_quote < 0.9 * $_SESSION['cart_total']) {

            $_SESSION['my_quote'] = rand(0.9 * $_SESSION['cart_total'], $_SESSION['my_quote']);


            echo 'Price Unacceptable. I can go upto : ' . $_SESSION['my_quote'];

        }


    } else {
        $errors[]="Please Enter Something";
    }

}



?>



  <center>Your Current Total IS : Rs. <?php echo $_SESSION['cart_total'] ?></center>

<div class="alert-warning">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="alert">&times</a>
    <?php if(!empty($errors)){echo output_errors($errors);} ?>

</div>



<form class="negotiation_form" action="" method="POST" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="user_quote" class="span4"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Quote !" class="btn ">  
</form>

<form action="" method="POST" class="negotiation_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="accept">
    <input type="submit" value="Accept / Checkout" class="btn ">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use jquery and send the request to the php file asynchronously to prevent the page from reloading.

Here is a basic script how to solve it on the client side:

```js
<script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        $.ajax({ url: '/PHP/File/Path', data: { param1: $('#Id_of_Input_field').val() }, type: "POST" })
    .success(function (result) {
      // do something with result
    });
    // prevent the page from submitting the form
    event.preventDefault();

  });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where do I add this script in my page? I forgot to mention that I don't have any experience in AJAX.

Comment: Well AJAX is short for asynchronous JavaScript and XML. Well the first part loading the jquery file you should put in the head of your html document, the second part you can put where you like because it will only load once jquery and the rest of the page is loaded $(function(){}) does this. Did you understand the rest of the code?